# Linux OS that usually takes less then 200 MB with a plugin-free Firefox as VNC

Tags: linux-distribution

Have a recommendation for a Linux OS that usually takes less then 200 MB of RAM when active with plugin-free Firefox?

I need one as a VNC in my Ubuntu server.

It doesn't matter for me from what branch it is: Debian/Fedora/BSD; I don't need almost anything besides surfing so it can be something dedicated for that, that comes secured from start because of its vast minimalism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) it includes 2 web browsers: Dillo and a minimalist **Firefox** and can run totally from RAM in 128 MB.  Runs on x86 machines only and is based on Debian/KDE.

Version 3.4.12 Screenshot
[image]

Version 4.4.10 Screenshot
[image]

Note that the *embedded* downloads include a version of qemu to act as its own VM on windows & Linux and still total about 50 MB.